# Where does scheduling algorithms run?

Tags: operating-system, job-scheduling

We see a list of scheduling algorithms which are supported by different Operating Systems.

Consider there are 2 processes (P1 and P2) running and scheduling algorithm is Round Robin. Now the P1 is running in the processor, P1 has completed its time slot. Now the scheduling algorithm has to do context switching (Take out P1 from the processor and bring in P2 to the processor).

I guess the concept what I have explained is correct.

Now, my question is that..

Scheduling algorithm itself is a process!! Lets name the scheduling algorithm as Ps.

Now Ps's job is to take out P1 from processor and bring in P2 to processor. In this case where does the Ps run? Does Ps also make use of the same processor? Or is there a special processor where Ps can run?

Comment: This looks like a classic university assignment question. Have you read your text book?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) because "_3. Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it._"

Answer (score 0):

The scheduling algorithm is not a process, so your question is based on a false assumption. The scheduling algorithm can begin running in the context of whatever process got interrupted, generally in kernel context. It then decides which process context to run in next and switches to that context. All along it basically ignores whatever process context it happened to be in when it began running.

Answer (score 0):

A modern operating system has two (or more) modes of operation, at least kernel and user. Each process has its own user mode address space. All processes share the same address space.

The kernel mode address space is only accessible in kernel mode.

The "operating system" is whenever the process is executing in kernel mode. Because there is only one kernel mode address space, it does not matter what process is executing in kernel mode to run the operating system.

The hardware timer triggers interrupts that the OS responds to in kernel mode. The OS checks to see if the current process (P1) has run out of time. If so, it switches the context to p2. Most of the switch is usually done in one instruction.

In this case, the processor enters kernel mode in P1 and returns to user mode in P2.